# How to I accept credit cards with the BigCommerce API

Tags: bigcommerce

I want to build a shopping cart in to a website I have created using the BigCommerce API. I want my customers to be able to select some products, put in there billing and shipping information, pay with a credit card and complete the purchase on my website. I have looked at the [BigCommerce API Documenation](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/orders) and see how to make orders (which is helpful), but not how to verify and accept credit card payments. Could someone guild me to the documentation on how to do that with the API or show me an example on how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

The Bigcommerce Orders API does not process credit card transactions. If you you are "creating" an order via the API, it is putting an externally created order into the Bigcommerce store.
If you need to process a credit card transaction on an external site, you would need to build this functionality into the site using the payment gateway of your choice. Your choice would prices the transaction through that gateway, and then you would insert the order back into your Bigcommerce store via the Orders API.
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/orders